# actions of notifications in android

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

First of all really sorry if this is a duplicate, although I think its not coz I have searched a lot but found nothing working. I want to remove the notification on click of cancel - which I found somewhere to call .cancel() method but where should i make that call. Other one when I click on accept or cancel the intent values comes same only which is "Notifications" in the logcat. Please let me know what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

My notification creator -

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, code.omnitrix.slidingmenu.MainActivity.class);
        if(message.contains("Blood Request")){
            intent1.putExtra("fragment", "Notifications");
            Log.d("Intent sent", intent1.getExtras().getString("fragment"));
        }else if(message.contains("Thank")){
            intent1.putExtra("fragment", "myDonations");
        }

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);        
        mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        //.setContentTitle("Thank you")
        if(message.contains("Blood Request")){
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Blood Request");
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, code.omnitrix.slidingmenu.MainActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("fragment", "accept");
            PendingIntent acceptIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, GcmBroadcastReceiver.class);
            intent3.putExtra("fragment", "reject-1");
            PendingIntent rejectIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent3, 0);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.tick_32, "Accept", acceptIntent);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.cross_32, "Reject", rejectIntent);
        }


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);   
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

While the other file that is intent receiver it is like -

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
            String fragmentToDisplay = intent.getStringExtra("fragment");
            Log.d("Vinit", "Intent Received");
            if(fragmentToDisplay!=null){
                Log.d("From Intent", fragmentToDisplay);
                if(fragmentToDisplay.equalsIgnoreCase("updateDetails")){
                    //show update details fragment
                    Fragment fragment = new UpdateDetails();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();      
                }else if(fragmentToDisplay.equalsIgnoreCase("Notifications")){
                    Fragment fragment = new Notifications();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
                }else if(fragmentToDisplay.equalsIgnoreCase("accept")){
                    //just send the response to the server.
                    //put in sqlite database.
                    Log.d("Fragment inside", "accept");
                }else if(fragmentToDisplay.equalsIgnoreCase("reject")){
                    //just remove the request from the notifications.
                    Log.d("Fragment inside", "reject");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) to remove notification on cancel click:
add this code in your reciever

```
 if(fragmentToDisplay.equalsIgnoreCase("reject")){
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(notificationId);
    Log.d("Fragment inside", "reject");
 }
```

PS: you used "**1**" as *notificationId* in your code (`mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());`) , the best way is to send it via putExtra() and retrieve it in your receiver.

2) sorry, i didn't understand the second part of your question. can you explain more?